# PHP Array push in loop doesn't change the array outside of the loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I've encountered the following problem:

```
private function getMyThemeIds($collection){
    $result = [];
    ...
      foreach ($results as $doc) {
        file_put_contents('2.txt', $doc->getUnid()); //everything is fine here

        $result[] = $doc->getUnid();

        file_put_contents('3.txt', print_r($result,true)); //again, array is just fine, barely 4000 entries
      }

    file_put_contents('4.txt', print_r($result,true)); // but here we see what was in this array right after initialization. Nothing in this case.
    return $result;
  }
```

I've tried different approaches - changed `foreach` to `for`, `$result[]` to `array_push`, etc with no avail. Anybody knows what the cause of this may be?

Comment: where id your $results ??

Comment: Not sure but you can use like $result = array(); for $result = []; while declaration..

Comment: What is your `php` version? If you are below `php-5.4` than change `$result = [];` to `$result = array();`

Comment: Does `$doc->getUnid(); ` prints proper output? It must not return empty.

Comment: @Rahautos, beyond that "..."

Comment: @Chayan, I tried, there was no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize array using 'array()'.Please follow below statment to initialize array

```
$result = array();
```

After initialize $result you can append data to it.
You can refer following link for array initialization-
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp

Comment: Variable was initialized with `$result = [];` as of `php-5.4`

Comment: Somehow... It worked. I can swear I already tried this! Well, thanks everybody.

Comment: array_push($result,$doc->getUnid());

Comment: @Moorindal Just curious to know, what is your php version?

Comment: @Silent_Coder, 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for details. You can try this.

```
private function getMyThemeIds($collection){
    $result = array();
    ...
      foreach ($results as $doc) {
        file_put_contents('2.txt', $doc->getUnid()); //everything is fine here

        $result[] = $doc->getUnid();

        file_put_contents('3.txt', serialize($result)); //again, array is just fine, barely 4000 entries
      }

    file_put_contents('4.txt', serialize($result)); // but here we see what was in this array right after initialization. Nothing in this case.
    return $result;
  }
```